# CRTP C++ Pattern and interfaces

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I am a beginner in C++ templates and stumbled upon following definition,

In general, CRTP is useful to factor out implementations of interfaces that can only be member functions (for example, constructor, destructors, and subscript operators).

And I am trying hard to understand what this means ?

Can anyone help me with a simple program...

Comment: Sorry, but beginners in C++ templates should not jump to CRTP. Learn easy application of templates first.

Comment: Thanks, the link was useful. Easy application of templates, would you suggest hand coding every program in the first few chapters, or some other way